# Convert php table to angularjs javascript approach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this data in php that generates table in html:

```
$data['html'] = "<html><body><table border=1><tr><td width='400px'><b>Username</b></td>";
   for ($y = 1; $y <= $calendar_days; $y++) {
     $data['html'] .= "<td width='30px'><b>".$y."</b></td>";
       $unique[$x] = 0;
       $total[$x] = 0;
    }
     $data['html'] .= "</tr>";

   foreach ($details as $users => $value) {
     $data['html'] .= "<tr><td>$users</td>";
        for ($x = 1; $x <= $calendar_days; $x++){
           $details[$users][$x] = empty($details[$users][$x]) ? SPACE : $details[$users][$x];       
           $data['html'] .= "<td>" . $details[$users][$x] . "</td>";
         }
$data['html'] . "</tr>";
   }
```

I have need now to convert it in angularjs, it is possible? I mean inside my controller I will create `$scope.data` variable and add `"<html><body><table border=1><tr><td width='400px'><b>Username</b></td>";` it. Then in my view I will call `data`? Is it wrong or right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to return your data in a JSON format for AngularJS. Instead of generating the whole  via PHP, simply arrange the data in a PHP variable and send it back as JSON, using encode_json(...). After that, in your HTML page, simply create a

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="object in items">
```

where ng-repeat represents the loop over the data you will receive.

And add a script to resolve these items:

```
var app = angular.module('myItems', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://my.url/my_objects.php").success(function (response) {
       $scope.items = response;
    });
});
```